# Unconnected item on circuit diagram

Tags: arduino

I'm looking to use a [CAN Bus shield](https://github.com/sparkfun/CAN-Bus_Shield) with my Arduino. The following is a circuit diagram for it: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/canbus_shield-v12.pdf

I am having trouble reading the circuit diagram (specifically the MCP2551 connections, which are in top right corner). I need to connect the chip to my vehicle's CAN Bus.

Do I have to connect to the DB9 Plug, or can I connect to the JP5 (draw right below it). I was unsure if it is implied that the two lead to the same place and either can be used.

Thanks in advance, I'm sure this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the two plugs are connected to the same places, however the JP5 is marked 'DNP' which implies it is not populated so you'd have to solder it on there (at best, at worst they've overlapped the footprints so it's not accessible without removing the 'DB9').

Looking at the Eagle file- in this case, it's the header behind the 'DB9' so you just need to populate it.

[image]

[image: Image from Sparkfun ad]

Answer (score 0):

You can connect either DB9 of JP5. They are connected to the same lines in parallel.